# Reactive form is validating for all iterations in the list

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using reactive forms inside *ngFor for validations in my application. But when I'm trying to validate only for one iteration, the form is being validated in all the iterations.

I tried using the template-driven form and it's working well. Below is the working code for the template-driven form

```
<div class="form-group col">
  <label>Flower License</label>
  <input type="text" name="fLicense" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="f.fLicense" #fLicense="ngModel" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': statusForm.submitted && fLicense.invalid }" required>
  <div *ngIf="statusForm.submitted && fLicense.invalid" class="invalid-feedback">
    <div *ngIf="fLicense.errors.required">flower License is required</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

For Reactive Approach, Below is my code
HTML

```
<div *ngFor="let f of flowers">
  <div>{{f.type}} </div>
  <form [formGroup]="statusForm" (ngSubmit)="submitStatus()">
    <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
      <label>Flower License</label>
      <input class="form-control" type="text" formControlName="fLicense" [class.invalid]="!statusForm.controls['fLicense'].valid && statusForm.controls['fLicense'].touched ">
      <div *ngIf="!statusForm.controls['fLicense'].valid && (statusForm.controls['fLicense'].touched || isSubmitted)">
        <div class="invalid-feedback" style="display: block;">Please enter flower License Number</div>
      </div>
  </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

ts

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.statusForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    fLicense: ['', Validators.required],
  });
}

submitStatus(f) {
  this.isSubmitted = true;
  // stop here if form is invalid
  if (this.statusForm.invalid) {
    return;
  }
}
```

I tried to do this using `FormArray`, but I'm not able to include `formControl` inside form array. It's throwing error

```
  const newArray = new FormArray({
      this.statusForm = new FormGroup({
        hempLicense: new FormControl(['', Validators.required])
      })

    });
```

Comment: Might help you in case of formArray https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-form-array-example

Comment: @PardeepJain That didn't work for me. Not able to understand where it's going wrong in my case

Comment: @PardeepJain I agree that your given URL example should help to resolve this matter.

Comment: @HADI does that mean URL code is not working? or I provided irrelevant code?

Comment: I meant url is fine, will exactly solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example - https://codesandbox.io/s/reactive-form-is-validating-for-all-iterations-in-the-list-ioijo

My proposed solution would be to create another component for form.

```js
<div *ngFor="let f of flowers">
  <app-flower-form [data]="f"></app-flower-form>
</div>
```

flower form component will look like this -

```js
export class FlowerFormComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() data: FlowerInterface = null;

  public isSubmitted: boolean;
  public statusForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.statusForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      fLicense: ["", Validators.required]
    });
  }

  submitStatus(f) {
    this.isSubmitted = true;

    if (this.statusForm.invalid) {
      return;
    }
  }
}
```

Inside flower form component html

```html
<form [formGroup]="statusForm" (ngSubmit)="submitStatus()">
  <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
    <h5>{{ data.type }}</h5>
    <label>Flower License</label>
    <input
      class="form-control"
      type="text"
      formControlName="fLicense"
      [class.invalid]="!statusForm.controls['fLicense'].valid && statusForm.controls['fLicense'].touched "
    />
    <div
      *ngIf="!statusForm.controls['fLicense'].valid && (statusForm.controls['fLicense'].touched || isSubmitted)"
    >
      <div class="invalid-feedback" style="display: block;">
        Please enter flower License Number
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking for similar approach to @Chellappan வ . But If I put two input fields, that's not working for me

Comment: What do you mean by two fields? you can add as many fields you want.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have array of value, you have to create FormArray instead of FormControl.

```
 this.statusForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      fLicense: this.formBuilder.array(this.createFLicenseArray(this.flowers))
 });

 createFLicenseArray(flowers) {
     return flowers.map(flower =>
      this.formBuilder.control("", [Validators.required]));
 }
```

Then loop formArray controls to show individual fLicense

```
<form [formGroup]="statusForm">
    <div class="form-group col-sm-4" formArrayName="fLicense" *ngFor="let flow of fLicenseArray.controls;let i = index">
        <label>Flower License</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" [formControlName]="i">
        <div *ngIf="!fLicenseArray.at(i).valid && (fLicenseArray.at(i).touched)">
            <div class="invalid-feedback" style="display: block;">Please enter flower License Number</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wn6nqq)

Comment: If there are more than one fields in the form, do i need to insert them into an object to return? If possible can you add one more field in the same form?

Comment: Yes, in my case, the form will contain more than one input fields. There will be four input fields in each iteration.

Comment: If possible can you update the same stackblitz. I'm looking for the similar approach to learn

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216425/discussion-between-sai-and-chellappan-).